# Haskell - Combining datatypes?

Tags: haskell, types

I'm new to Haskell, I've looked around for an answer to the below but had no luck.

Why doesn't this code compile?

```
newtype Name = Name String deriving (Show, Read)
newtype Age = Age Int deriving (Show, Read)
newtype Height = Height Int deriving (Show, Read)

data User = Person Name Age Height deriving (Show, Read)

data Characteristics a b c = Characteristics a b c

exampleFunction :: Characteristics a b c -> User
exampleFunction (Characteristics a b c) = (Person (Name a) (Age b) (Height c))
```

Error:

```
"Couldn't match expected type ‘String’ with actual type ‘a’,‘a’ is a rigid type, variable bound by the type signature"
```

However, this compiles just fine:

```
exampleFunction :: String -> Int -> Int -> User
exampleFunction a b c = (Person (Name a) (Age b) (Height c))
```

I realize there's simpler ways of doing the above, but I'm just testing the different uses of custom data types.

**Update:**

My inclination is that the compiler doesn't like 'exampleFunction ::Characteristics  a b c' because its not type safe. i.e. I'm providing no guarantee of: a == Name String, b == Age Int, c == Height Int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exampleFunction` is too general. You are claiming it can take a `Characteristics a b c` value for *any* types `a`, `b`, and `c`. However, the value of type `a` is passed to `Name`, which can *only* take a value of type `String`. The solution is to be specific about what types the characteristics can actually be.

```
exampleFunction :: Characteristics String Int Int -> User
exampleFunction (Characteristics a b c) = (Person (Name a) (Age b) (Height c))
```

Consider, though, that you may not even need `newtype`s here; simple type aliases may suffice.

```
type Name = String
type Age = Int
type Height = Int

type Characteristics = (,,)

exampleFunction :: Characteristics Name Age Height -> User
exampleFunction (Charatersics n a h) = Person n a h
```

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question at the same time with pretty much this :p

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
exampleFunction :: Characteristics String Int Int -> User
exampleFunction (Characteristics a b c) = (Person (Name a) (Age b) (Height c))
```

The reason this works, and yours does not, is that Name, Age and Height require specific types where your example function took completely generic arguments.

The a,b and c in this line of your example defines the type of the arguments, not the name of them.

```
 exampleFunction :: Characteristics a b c
```

Comment: This does not explain the error, just slaps down the compiler :-)

Comment: added some explanation